# Split array into chunks function not working properly | JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I wrote this function that should split a given array into given pieces:

```
function makeGrid(array, pieces){
    var i, output = [], temp;
    for (i = 0; i <= array.length; i += pieces){
        temp = array.slice(i, i+pieces);
        output.push(temp);
    }
    return output;
}
```

But when I test it out on my site with an array of length 25 and into 5 chunks I get this:
[image]

And whenever I test it out on pythontutor.com it functions correctly, does somebody know what the problem is?

Comment: Your code works, how are you calling it

Comment: I'm simply doing `console.log(makeGrid(tiles, $("#input-columns").val()))` where `tiles` is the array of length 25 with shuffled numbers and `$("#input-columns").val()` is the value of the input which is 5 in my case

Comment: can you share a fiddle to replicate this problem?

Comment: Call me a newbie, but what is a fiddle?

Comment: Not sure how to use that but I have an update: whenever I replace `$("#input-columns").val()` with a real number it works fine

Comment: please add the original array in text form.

Comment: Debug your code by walking through it in a debugger and examining variables along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not sure how to use that but I have an update: whenever I replace
>   $("#input-columns").val() with a real number it works fine

It seems you need to parse the input's value to an integer first

```
makeGrid(tiles, parseInt($("#input-columns").val(), 10))
```

otherwise `i += pieces` will become `i += "5"` and the `i` becomes `55`

which is why your counter is only running twice.

Comment: I'm quiet sure that the value is an int because I set the input as a number

Comment: @Karatawi val() method returns value of type `string` only regardless of its `type` attribute value.